# Rich web application platform suggestions

Tags: web-applications, ria, web-frameworks, intranet

We have decided to develop a real time monitoring intranet application. User number for this tool will be approximately 50+. Considering the trends we have decided it to be web based. Our back end servers extensively java, however communication between real time monitoring agent and servers will be based on xml, so we can consider using .net technologies also.
Mobility support for chosen platform is necessary although its not our primary concern at the moment.
Considering our situations which rich client web application plaform will you recommend ? Please consider learning curve and online community support in your suggestions.

Comment: Why not simple html5 css3 and jquery on the client side? On the server-side you might want to take a look at jboss for its replication (read multicasting) and memory sharing properties (read infinispan) and scheduler (read quartz)

Answer (score 0):

Given your Java back-end infrastructure, I would suggest GWT as an obvious option.

[Google Web Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/)

Comment: Actually its a good option however questions(or rumors) about GWT's future make us little reluctant.